# how to fit large wider and heigher table for all screen at bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I've faced a problem with bootstrap table. Basically, my table will be dynamic and at first some columns will be hidden. Some/All hidden column will be showed dynamically based on user's action. When, many/all columns are shown, a scroll-bar will come at the bottom of my browser window. But, I want that scroll-bar come to my table instead of page/browser window. I mean, this is happened now which I don't want:

[image]

I want bootstrap `.table-responsive` feature for my larger screen too when my table's width cross the visible width of the browser:

[image]

Also I want vertical scroll-bar when it'll cross a definite height. To make this, I've applied a css like this:

```
.table-custom {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

which is not working. And for horizontal scroll-bar(when table's width cross the parent's width), I can't apply any fixed width as I've to concern about all large and small screen. So, what can I do to appear scroll-bars(both vertical and horizontal) when the dynamic table cross the width and height of it's parent div?

[My fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/learner73/vwrva9L6/9/embedded/result/)

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/vwrva9L6/11/ If so, you should apply `overflow: scroll;` to a containing element of your table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply need to apply `overflow: scroll;` to a containing element of your table, which you already have with `.table-responsive`.

```
.table-responsive {
     max-width: 150px;
     overflow: scroll;
}
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vwrva9L6/11/

Comment: This is okay. One thing, you can see that .table-responsive have some different style for smaller than 767px screen(at that time .table-responsive will be active-we can say). I wish if I can get that style for larger screen too when dynamic table cross it's parent's width/height and scroll-bar appear for that. Still, I accept your answer as I didn't make clear this at my post. Thanks

Comment: I'm unclear as to what you're looking to do here. `.table-responsive` is contained in a Bootstrap column group, `col-lg-6`, which will affect how much of the content area it will take up. For larger screens it will take up 50% of the width while smaller screens 100% of the width. If you want 100% width for your table all of the time you might have to use `col-lg-12` or not use Bootstrap rows and column groups altogether.